# Get only first image in blade template from foreach loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

We have two tables room and room images. I am using relation in both tables and want to get the first image from room images table (For thumbnail). Below foreach loop is working fine on single detail page. Now i want to get the thumbnail image for main page.

```
@foreach ($room->tbl_roomimages as $single_img)
    <img src="/storage/cover_images/{{$single_img->room_image}}" alt="">
@endforeach
```

I am using hasMany relation for Room images in room model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a function inside your model to get the first image.

Example:

```
public function getFirstImageAttribute()
{
    return $this->hasOne('RoomImageModel');
}
```

And use that function to get the first image for your room.

```
<img src="/storage/cover_images/{{ $room->firstImage }}" alt="">
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks!
Although i get the first image like this.

```
@foreach($room->tbl_roomimages as $single_img)
    @if($room->tbl_roomimages->first()==$single_img)
        {{$single_img->room_image}} 
    @endif 
@endforeach
```

Comment: There's so many different ways to do everything, my answer was just something I thought of before leaving for work.

Comment: You are absolutely right!
Can you please explain more where(*query to get required image*) query? How we can get one record from db?

Comment: When using relationships, you can add on additional statements such as where. So I tossed a where statement into my query in order to get the first image I desired. I am unaware of how you choose what image is first, like if you sort them by a date or sequence, or if you just choose the first one from the database. So you can sort them by date, then using ->first() will pull the first result that matches your query in the database.

Comment: @ImJT I don't want to use where query then it will be like this? 

`public function getThumbnailImage()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\RoomImage')->first();
    }`

Comment: The following code return the file name but when i use it without dd function, It shows an error `Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\hostelproject\resources\views\pages\roomslist.blade.php)`

`{{ dd($room->getThumbnailImage()->room_image) }}`

Comment: I just noticed I made a mistake. When using `->hasOne();`, you aren't required to use `->first();` because `->hasOne();` is already limiting you to one result. So using `return $this->hasOne('App\RoomImage');` should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192062/discussion-between-imjt-and-faizi).